# How to load json in serverside rendering with angular universal

Tags: json, node.js, angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am building an angular2-universal app for a university project for my bachelor thesis. I want to get this app rendered on the server with angular universal. How can I get my .json files loaded on the server? In my version without serverside rendering, I use a service to get the jsons with an http.get request like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class VideoService {

private movieSubject: BehaviorSubject<Video[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Video[]>([]);
  movies$: Observable<Video[]> = this.movieSubject.asObservable();

constructor(private http : Http) {
    this.http.get('./json/movies/movies.json').subscribe(
      res => this.movieSubject.next(res.json()),
      error => console.error(error)
    )
}
}
```

In my component I get the json with following code:

```
movieInfos: MovieInfos;

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) {
    movieService.movies$.subscribe(
      infos => this.movieInfos = infos,
      error => console.error(error)
    );
  }
```

And in the template I use the code below to Inject the data to another component:

```
<app-info-site *ngIf="movieInfos" [movieInfos]="movieInfos"></app-info-site>
```

When I use this code with angular universal, it still works, but the part of the site which belongs to the json is loaded the first time on the client and because of the ngIf the server ignores this part of the code so I get an incomplete .html file from the server. How can I get this to be loaded on the server to get a complete .html site from there?

PS: I am completely new to angular2 and serverside rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend you to migrate to Angular4 as Server Side Rendering is now part of Angular4 and Angular Universal is not required as such...

You may also checkout http://rajdeepdeb.me/angular-server-side-rendering-with-a-simple-node-server/

To answer in your existing structure you should move your http calls from constructor to the ngOnInit by implementing OnInit from

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    ...other variable and functions...
    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get('./json/movies/movies.json').subscribe(
            res => this.movieSubject.next(res.json()),
            error => console.error(error)
        );
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any other support...

Comment: I remember attempting something like this recently and got an error saying that I needed to use absolute paths. What makes this work without using abs. paths? Cheers! (not currently on a PC / can't try out the code on my setup)

Comment: @rex looking at the article you posted, you're not actually using Angular Univeral for the server-side rendering. I'm using Angular 6 and would love to stip out Universal and just build the simple NodeJS Server instead.